# Why is `npm version` not committing the updated package.json?

Tags: node.js, git, npm, travis-ci

I'm using Travis to publish an npm module to npmjs.org.

The relevant part of `.travis.yml` is:

```
before_deploy:
  - npm version minor
  - git config credential.helper "store --file=.git/credentials"
  - echo "https://${GH_TOKEN}:@github.com" > .git/credentials
  - git push && git push --tags
```

I'm seeing that the tag is created, but the change to `package.json` is *not* making it to the git repo.

Looking at the logs from `travis-ci.org`, I see:

```
$ npm version minor
v1.3.0

$ git config credential.helper "store --file=.git/credentials"

$ echo "https://${GH_TOKEN}:@github.com" > .git/credentials

$ git push && git push --tags
Everything up-to-date
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads.
Compressing objects:  25% (1/4)   
Compressing objects:  50% (2/4)   
Compressing objects:  75% (3/4)   
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4)   
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects:  25% (1/4)   
Writing objects:  50% (2/4)   
Writing objects:  75% (3/4)   
Writing objects: 100% (4/4)   
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 411 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/Jellyvision/basecamp-api.git
 * [new tag]         v1.3.0 -> v1.3.0
```

So, it's pretty clear that the change to package.json didn't get added or committed, since the `push` shows that everything is up to date.

The new tag *is* pushed up, for what it's worth.

When I run `npm version minor` locally, I see the new commit being generated as expected, so I'm guessing this is environment related, but I can't find anything in the documentation that suggests that `npm version` would work differently in a CI environment.

Any suggestions as to what's going on here?

Comment: @Downvoter: can you give me some indication of how this question could be improved, please?

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9111

Comment: Thanks, but package.json is at the root of my repository.

Comment: I am having the same thing but locally. Did you ever find a fix?

Answer (score 4):

We created this `publish.sh` script to first update the npm package version and then updating our repository ...

```
#!/bin/sh
npm version $1
git push --follow-tags
npm publish
```

Example Usage:

```
%> ./publish.sh 2.2.41
```

Notice the use of `git push --follow-tags`.  This has the effect of changing the version in the `package.json` file, creating a tag release in git using the version in the `package.json` and updating the `master` branch.

Comment: Bam. `git push --follow-tags` was what I needed to get this working in a GitHub Action. A great, clear answer. Thanks!

Comment: Needed to add `--follow-tags` as well, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem.

Using the flag `--git-tag-version` works for me.

```
npm version minor --git-tag-version
```